# How can I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` headless with "[info] Restarting NetworkManager"

Tags: ssh, dpkg, networkmanager

An installation was interrupted. To fix it, I need to run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

However, I'm headless (Ubuntu, Raspberry Pi), and connect via ssh. `dpkg` wants to restart the network manager, i.e., I get

```
[info] Restarting NetworkManager
```

and then the ssh connection hangs. Maybe there's a prompt or something? Does anybody know why this hangs? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This was a specific issue with the home-assistant installer / WiFi, rather than a generic Ubuntu problem.

The installer runs

```
systemctl restart "${SERVICE_NM}"
```

which causes WiFi to disconnect. See comment thread here, https://peyanski.com/how-to-install-home-assistant-supervised-official-way/, comment by Tom at 11/02/2022 at 3:34 pm. Solution written up here and filed as a bug report:
https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/issues/273